# TIdFTP.Put() and TIdFTP.Get() give unexpected results

Tags: delphi, ftp, delphi-7, indy

I have Delphi 7 running on XP SP3.

On my server, I have this directory:

> root/public_html/TESTTEST

When I do this:

```
procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);     // connect
begin
  ftp.Host := 'URL';
  ftp.port := 21;
  ftp.Username := 'xxxxxxx';
  ftp.password := 'pppppp';
  ftp.Connect;    
  ...
```

The `TIdFTP` component connects wonderfully.

And when I expand the code to this:

```
  ...
  ftp.ChangeDir('/public_html');
  ftp.ChangeDir('/public_html/TESTTEST');
  ShowMessage(ftp.RetrieveCurrentDir);
  ...
```

It shows me:

> public_html/TESTTEST

Just for test, I did this:

```
FTP.makedir('TESTDIR');
```

And the directory does exist.

> public_html/TESTTEST/TESTDIR

Back to `public_html/TESTTEST`, if I try to use `ftp.Put(file1,file2,true);` I get this error message:

> I won't open connection to  100.126.38.39  (only 77.106.146.15)

Same error when I try `ftp.Get(file1,file2,true);`

File1 and 2 are adjusted accordingly to I/O, True/False switched - no difference, same error.

When I call `ftp.Get(...)`, the resulting file is created, but it is EMPTY.

To be honest, I don't know what to do. How can I make this work?

Comment: Try setting `TIdFTP.Passive` to true. It is false by default. FTP transfers are performed on a secondary TCP connection, in either Active mode (FTP server connects to client) or Passive mode (client connects to FTP server). It sounds like the FTP server is not able to, or unwilling to, connect to you in Active mode.

Comment: My sincere Thanks. That did the job.